# Bitbucket YLM pipeline to deploy on Digital Ocean

Tags: bash, deployment, git, bitbucket, pipelining

I am following [this](https://refwarlockprog.wordpress.com/2017/11/25/bitbucket-pipelines-vm-deployment-digital-ocean/#more-164) guide to create a pipeline to deploy my Django project to Digital Ocean, Ubuntu 18 droplet.

**What I have done**

1. SSH key generated and added to my remote server and bitbucket
2. Synced yml file with project
3. bitbucket-pipelines.yml

```
image: python:3.7.3

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        name: Build and test
        caches:
          - pip
        script: # Modify the commands below to build your repository.
          - pip install -r requirements.txt
          - nosetests test/autotests --with-xunit --xunit-file=nosetests.xml --with-coverage --all-modules
    - step:
        name: Deploy to <myserver>
        script:
          - cat <script>.sh | ssh <user>@<host>
          - echo "Deploy step finished"
```

**ERRORS**
When I run the pipeline on Bitbucket I get the following ERROR

```
nosetests test/autotests --with-xunit --xunit-file=nosetests.xml --with-coverage --all-modules
<1s
+ nosetests test/autotests --with-xunit --xunit-file=nosetests.xml --with-coverage --all-modules
bash: nosetests: command not found
```

**Questions**

- `ssh <user>@<host>` I do understand how to replace `<user>` & `<host>`
- A.) How I should replace `<script>` at `cat <script>.sh`
- B.) How I should replace `<myserver>` at `name: Deploy to <myserver>` is this my server's IP address?
- C.) at the bottom section [this](https://refwarlockprog.wordpress.com/2017/11/25/bitbucket-pipelines-vm-deployment-digital-ocean/#more-164) guide has the following code I do not know what to do whit this?

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo "Deploy script started"
cd <project git directory>
git pull
sh <restart project>.sh
echo "Deploy script finished execution"
```